# Convert elements in array of objects from int to float python numpy

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

See code below, I have array `y`, which is a `numpy` object array.

I am trying to convert only `[15, 7, 9, 10, 7, 8, 20, 16, 9]` to floats like this: `[15.0, 7.0, 9.0, 10.0, 7.0, 8.0, 20.0, 16.0, 9.0]`.

How can I do that with numpy or panda?

```
df = pd.read_csv('./body.csv')
data = df.values

cols = range(0, 8) 
X = data[:, cols]
N, M = X.shape

classLab = data[:,-1]
y = classLab
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `df['col0'] = df['col0'].astype(float)`

Comment: Didn't work, I get this error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

Comment: First, you cannot convert only part of a numpy array to a different type (or you would get an array of `object`, some of which would be `int` and some `float`). It's all or nothing. Numpy arrays are preferably homogeneous. Second, please do not post images of code or data. Third, what you show hints at a pandas DataFrame, not a numpy array (because of index and column). Fourth, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PierreD first I am new at python, therefore everything is a bit confusing. Next I am using panda to read the data, and then using numpy to change the data, therefore I thought that I had to use numpy, but it sounds like it is also possible to use panda.

Comment: the question is: what are you trying to achieve?  The simplest is to convert the whole column into `float`, either at the time of reading or afterwards.

Comment: @PierreD I have provided a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: almost! You need to provide a sample of the file `'./body'` (and rename it `'body.csv'` for clarity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `pandas.read_csv()`, then you can ensure a type at the time of reading:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', dtype={'mycolumn': float})
```

Alternatively, you can do it after reading:

```py
df['mycolumn'] = df['mycolumn'].astype(float)
```

In either case, the whole column (stored as a numpy array) is converted to the type of choice. You cannot have only a few elements as `float` and the others as `int`.

The same is true if dealing with a numpy array for multiple columns:

```py
X = data.loc[:, 0:8].astype(float)
```